# How to convert from object to something more readable like IDictionary

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm happy to see 4.0.2 has support for .net 3.5, however there are no samples to understand how to use it, without dynamic keyword.

For example I have

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(GetSettings());                

object result = app.Fql(string.Format("SELECT id,name,type FROM profile WHERE id={0}", strID));
```

What is the simplest way to convert result to Dictionary or something more useful ?

Answer (score 2):

Found it, not as sexy as dynamic 4.0, but it works:

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(GetSettings());
var result = app.Fql(string.Format("SELECT id,name,type FROM profile WHERE id={0}", strID));
var dicResult = ((JsonArray)result)[0] as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

Hope it will help another 3.5 developer

Answer (score 0):

a Dictionary is generaly a 2 item list.

Dictionary(TKey, TValue)

Under the circumstances from your sql you'll be getting back 3 fields in your result, and unless i'm missing something it should only be 1 result set.

a single object with 3 parameters should be sufficent.

Now if your returning multiple lines with only two fields... now thats a different story.

Comment: Patrick, the returned answer name=value, so I think dictionary is the way to go, for example:   "id": "1234",
   "name": "Jack Juiceson",
   "first_name": "Jack",
   "last_name": "Juiceson", etc.

Comment: i would tend to disagree... a dictionary is better suited (imo) when you have a repeating list of values using the same parameters... example; Dictionary<string, string> Name; the items in the dictionary would be Name["Bob"] = "Bob Smith"; Name["Fred"] = "Fred Jones"; etc.. What you need is a value object which you can then serialize to json... also it would have probably helped in your original question if you mentioned that you were using json... that changes things a little.